# Prevent Google from Indexing My Name Servers

Tags: .htaccess, nameservers

I have a VPS Hosting account with 2 domains.  I just looked on Google to view the pages indexed for one of the sites and noticed that one of the results was one of my nameservers.  As far as I am concerned, Google should not be indexing this.

Additionally, when you click on the link and go to it, the page loads as the 2nd website's home page.  I fear that this is a problem for 2 reasons... 1- Duplicate Content, 2- Associating content between 2 sites.

Name Servers:
NS1.DOMAINA.COM
NS2.DOMAINA.COM

Domains:
DOMAINA.com
DOMAINB.com

When I clicked on NS1.DOMAINA.COM and NS2.DOMAINA.COM, they both pulled content from DOMAINB.COM.  The nameservers are being indexed as DOMAINA.COM pages however.

After reading several resources, it seems that this issue resulted in band-aid fixes such as robots.txt rules, etc.  I would rather fix the problem but if that is not probable, I would prefer to do this in .htaccess.  However, I am nor exactly proficient in htaccess so I would require examples or detailed explanations.

Thank you

Comment: The ONLY things that I want removed from the index are ns1.domaina.com and ns2.domaina.com. All the pages for domaina.com and domainb.com should be left as is and indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a file named `robots.txt` at the root of the domain you wish to remove the indexation, and fill it with this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

You can also set this bunch of lines on your `.htaccess` :

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
```

EDIT: Also, to block only the subdomain, add a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DOMAINA.COM$
RewriteRule ^robotx\.txt$ robots-subdomain.txt
```

Comment: I have a robots.txt file on DOMAINA.COM already.  What would Disallow: / do?

Comment: NS1.DOMAINA.COM is loading an exact replica of DOMAINB.COM and that page is a separate site which also needs to be indexed.

Comment: The first line (User-agent) means that the command is applied for every robots, the second line (Disallow) is used to block the reading of every content on the domain for those robots (`/` is the root)

Comment: I figured that would block the entire site... that's not what I want to do.  I have 2 sites, both need to be fully indexed.  The only things needing to be removed from Google's index is ns1.domaina.com and ns2.domaina.com.